# fprint doesn't work in loop

Tags: c, file, loops, printf

I am trying to repeatedly read a string from the command line and print it to a file. This is my code:

```
int main ()
{
    FILE* fp=fopen("test.txt","w");
    char* tofile[10];
    while(1){
        printf("cat: ");
        scanf("%s",tofile);
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n",tofile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works just fine outside the loop. But inside, it just doesn't print.

The fprintf function returns the correct amount of characters it has to print.

Note: I know there's a [similar question out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305530/fprintf-doesnt-print-when-it-undergoes-a-loop), but it hasn't been answered yet, and I hope my code can help in this matter since it's simpler.

Comment: If you want to be able to have data written without closing the file, you need to flush any buffers with `fflush(fp)`. (Not everything is line-buffered.)

Comment: Do you really mean to read "*from the command line*", which you're not doing at all, or do you mean to read from the standard input, which is what you're actually doing?

Comment: Well, @Ryan, *eventually* the buffer would fill and get flushed.  But you're probably right that buffering is what has the OP confused.  He's probably not sending enough input before he checks the file, so that nothing has been flushed yet at that point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The loop appears to be meant to be exited with ^C, so it’s not necessarily true that the buffer will eventually fill. (Note how the return value of `scanf` is being ignored.)

Comment: That buffer of size 20 is very small and very easily overflowed. Make it bigger: 4096, or perhaps just 256.   You also need to terminate the loop on EOF.  You’re not checking your input succeeded.

Comment: **In addition** to the flushing issue, `char * toline [10]` is the **wrong type** for `*scanf %s` and `*printf %s` and a good compiler should at least warn you, although since these are varargs diagnosis is not required. This particular error case will work on most if not all systems, but many similar errors will cause problems and even disasters so you should learn not to make them. @JonathanLeffler: although sizeof ptr == 2 is possible it is quite rare nowadays; otherwise concur.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: the `20` was an iPhone typo for `10`, and I'd not noticed that we were playing with an array of `char *` rather than an array of `char` — partly because of limited screen space, partly because of dog-walking distractions, and mostly because I wasn't reading carefully enough.

Answer (score 2):

Well first it doesn't seem that what you want is reading on the command line.
The command line what you write right when you execute your program such as:

```
./main things that are on the command line
```

What it seems you want to do is to read on the standard input.

What you should consider is to use the `fgets` function, as it has a limit of characters to be read, so that you can store them "safely" into a buffer, like your `tofile`.
As you want to read on the standard input you can use the `stdin` stream (which is a FILE* that is automatically created for every program)

The line goes

```
fgets(tofile, 10, stdin);
```

Your loop becoming :

```
while (fgets(tofile, 10, stdin) != NULL) {
  printf("cat: ");
  fprintf(fp, "%s\n", tofile);
}
```

meaning: as long as we can read on the standard input, print "cat :" and store what we just read in the file controlled by the stream pointer `fp`.

### Some important stuff

When you try to open a stream it may fail and you should test it:

```
char filename[] = "test.txt";
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");

if (fp == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file of name : %s", filename);
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Right before exiting your main, you should also close the file and check if it has succeeded, like that for example:

```
  if (fclose(fp) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close the file of name : %s", filename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

The whole thing becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  char filename[] = "test.txt";

  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file of name : %s", filename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char tofile[10];

  printf("cat: ");

  while (fgets(tofile, 10, stdin) != NULL) {
    printf("cat: ");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", tofile);
  }

  if (fclose(fp) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close the file of name : %s", filename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Improvements

I don't know if it is just a little program or it aspires to become a greater program.
In the last case you should consider using defines and not a magical number such as

```
#define BUFFER_MAX_SIZE 10

char tofile[BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];
while (fgets(tofile, BUFFER_MAX_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) { ... }
```

This helps for readability and makes the program less apt to debug when modifying such a size. Because with the define all the part of the code needing the size will still be fully functional without modifying them.

---

Please also keep in mind that your `tofile` acts as a buffer, and it's really a small buffer that can easily be overflowed.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. Section _some important stuff_ is not helpful though, it's nothing to do with the problem. I shrinked the code to be as short as possible (who wants to read all the way through 500 lines if the issue can be expressed in 20?)

Answer (score 0):

This will work. [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) returns the string it reads from the specified file pointer. If this string returns only a newline ("\n"), that means nothing was entered at `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt","w");
    // always check if fopen() == null

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not write to file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char tofile[30];
    printf("cat: ");
    while (fgets(tofile, 30, stdin)) {
        if (strcmp(tofile, "\n") == 0)
            break;
        fprintf(fp, "%s", tofile);
        printf("cat: ");
    }

    // always fclose()
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edited code.**

Comment: `fgets()` returns NULL on EOF, and a string comparison with a null pointer yields undefined behaviour.  You're looking for an empty line, not EOF.  That may also be legitimate, but only after you've checked for EOF (null-ness) from `fgets()`.